# How to determine monthly run time for different subsets in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, intervals

I'm new to python and struggling with the following;

I have a dataframe build out of following fields: Date','Machine Type','Total Run Hours'

```
Date      Machine   TRH

27-02-2018  ...     ... 
01-03-2018   A      2200
01-03-2018   B      5700
02-03-2018   A      2204
09-03-2018   B      5709
15-03-2018   B      5715
18-03-2018   A      2214
25-03-2018   A      2222
29-03-2018   B      5720
31-03-2018   A      2230
01-04-2018  ...     ...
```

I would like to determine the monthly hours run by each type of machine and store it in an additional column.

Monthly hours can be determined by next formula:
Hours at the lasts date of the month - Hours at the first day of the month

For machine A: (2230 - 2200) = 30

For machine B: (5720 - 5700) = 20

The outcome should be:

```
Date      Machine   TRH     Monthly TRH

27-02-2018  ...     ...        ...
01-03-2018   A      2200       30
01-03-2018   B      5700       20
02-03-2018   A      2204       30
09-03-2018   B      5709       20
15-03-2018   B      5715       20
18-03-2018   A      2214       30
25-03-2018   A      2222       30
29-03-2018   B      5720       20
31-03-2018   A      2230       30
01-04-2018  ...     ...        ...
```

I've no clue how to solve this problem. Should I use groupby? should I refer to labda? I hope one of you can answer my question. Many thanks!

Comment: Please format your data so it is readable.

Comment: The first rule of Pandas is don't use lambdas.  Groupby is a great first idea.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

```
'''
Date      Machine   TRH
01-03-2018   A      2200
01-03-2018   B      5700
02-03-2018   A      2204
09-03-2018   B      5709
15-03-2018   B      5715
18-03-2018   A      2214
25-03-2018   A      2222
29-03-2018   B      5720
31-03-2018   A      2230
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst = True)
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date), inplace = True)
df.TRH = pd.to_numeric(df.TRH).copy()

monthly = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'), 'Machine']).TRH.last() - df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'), 'Machine']).TRH.first()).to_frame(name = 'Monthly TRH').reset_index()

monthly['month'] = monthly.Date.dt.to_period('M')
monthly.drop('Date', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df['month'] = df.Date.dt.to_period('M')

df.merge(monthly).drop('month', axis = 1)
```

[image: out]

## Edit

The first method is faster, but here's another way to do it:

```
'''
Date      Machine   TRH
01-03-2018   A      2200
01-03-2018   B      5700
02-03-2018   A      2204
09-03-2018   B      5709
15-03-2018   B      5715
18-03-2018   A      2214
25-03-2018   A      2222
29-03-2018   B      5720
31-03-2018   A      2230
'''

# clean up
df = pd.read_clipboard().sort_values('Date')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst = True)
df['month'] = df.Date.dt.to_period('M')
df.TRH = pd.to_numeric(df.TRH).copy()

# do it in one go
df.groupby([
    'month',
    'Machine'
]).nth([
    0,
    -1
]).groupby([
    'month',
    'Machine'
]).diff().drop(columns = 'Date').dropna().reset_index().rename(columns = {
    'TRH' : 'Monthly TRH'
}).merge(df).drop(columns = 'month')
```

Same results, different column order.

[image: alternate]

Comment: Both solutions work! Thanks for that! However, I would like to store these values (20 and 30) in an additional column (Monthly TRH), applicable for the data of each row of the input dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing someone will come up with a better way than 2 groupbys, but this will work.

First sort the dates (making sure they are datetime), and then use `first` and `last` with a groupby machine and month (and year if the data spans more than 1 year).

```
import pandas as pd
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year
df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month

df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
temp = (df.groupby(['Machine', 'Year', 'Month'])['TRH'].last()-
 df.groupby(['Machine', 'Year', 'Month'])['TRH'].first()).reset_index().rename(columns={'TRH': 'Monthly TRH'}

#  Machine  Year  Month  Monthly TRH
#0       A  2018      3         30.0
#1       B  2018      3         20.0
```

To then bring it back you can merge

```
df.merge(temp, on=['Month', 'Year', 'Machine'], how='left').drop(columns=['Month', 'Year'])

#         Date Machine     TRH  Monthly TRH
#0  2018-02-27     ...     ...          ...
#1  2018-03-01       A  2200.0         30.0
#2  2018-03-02       A  2204.0         30.0
#3  2018-03-18       A  2214.0         30.0
#4  2018-03-25       A  2222.0         30.0
#5  2018-03-31       A  2230.0         30.0
#6  2018-03-01       B  5700.0         20.0
#7  2018-03-09       B  5709.0         20.0
#8  2018-03-15       B  5715.0         20.0
#9  2018-03-29       B  5720.0         20.0
#10 2018-04-01     ...     ...          ...
```

Comment: @L.Scheipers I updated it to bring it back to the original `DataFrame`